# Firebase Crashlytics reporting mystery crashes

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I have a Flutter app targeting Android.

Submitting to the Play Store insternal testing, no issues are reported. I also did a Firebase Robo test on a few devices, all clean.

But Crashlytics is reporting dozens of crashes coming from Google machines. Main one is:

> Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError:
> Null check operator used on a null value. Error thrown null.

I looked at the stack trace but there is nothing that makes sense to me in there.
I tried using `flutter symbolize` to de-obfuscate the trace, but it still looks like Greek to me!

`flutter symbolize -i ./build/symbols/stack.txt -d ./build/symbols/app.android-arm64.symbols |more`

I am not sure if this is a false report by Crashlytics, or is there something I need to fix here. How do I even investigate this?

```
# Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Application: app.myapp
# Platform: android
# Version: 1.0.11 (11)
# Issue: 0e1a67110958092c5b5d627bd3bbf313
# Session: 6379F18601E600C92CAE49F9D7E36C5A_DNE_0_v2
# Date: Sun Nov 20 2022 22:21:10 GMT+1300 

Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Null check operator used on a null value. Error thrown null.
BuildId: 4269d6000abb454d5f35d98538efa35f
#00 abs 0 virt 00000000005f5f67 _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x4717c7
#01 abs 0 virt 00000000005c92de _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x444b3e
#02 abs 0 virt 00000000001957da _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x1103a
#03 abs 0 virt 000000000019576d _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x10fcd
#04 abs 0 virt 00000000001952ee _kDartIsolateSnapshotInstructions+0x10b4e

pool-63-thread-1:
#00 pc 0x0 app.myapp 
#01 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park [LockSupport.java:194])
#02 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081])
#03 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176])
#04 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:905])
#05 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063])
#06 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123])
#07 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637])
#08 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.lang.Thread.run [Thread.java:1012])

pool-79-thread-1:
#00 pc 0x0 app.myapp 
#01 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park [LockSupport.java:194])
#02 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081])
#03 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176])
#04 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:905])
#05 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063])
#06 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123])
#07 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637])
#08 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.lang.Thread.run [Thread.java:1012])

.
.
.

ScionFrontendApi:
#00 pc 0x0 app.myapp 
#01 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos [LockSupport.java:234])
#02 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123])
#03 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll [LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458])
#04 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062])
#05 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123])
#06 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637])
#07 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.lang.Thread.run [Thread.java:1012])

pool-146-thread-1:
#00 pc 0x0 app.myapp 
#01 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park [LockSupport.java:194])
#02 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081])
#03 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176])
#04 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:905])
#05 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063])
#06 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123])
#07 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637])
#08 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.lang.Thread.run [Thread.java:1012])

pool-88-thread-1:
#00 pc 0x0 app.myapp 
#01 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park [LockSupport.java:194])
#02 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081])
#03 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176])
#04 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:905])
#05 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063])
#06 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123])
#07 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637])
#08 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.lang.Thread.run [Thread.java:1012])

pool-102-thread-1:
#00 pc 0x0 app.myapp 
#01 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park [LockSupport.java:194])
#02 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await [AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081])
#03 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176])
#04 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:905])
#05 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063])
#06 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123])
#07 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run [ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637])
#08 pc 0x0 app.myapp (java.lang.Thread.run [Thread.java:1012])
```

Comment: I may be mistaken but to me, this looks like Crashlytics is reporting a crash caused by itself. The null-check error means something is being force unwrapped (using `!`) when it is null. Can you reproduce the error on your own devices? What are the other details of the crash? Eg. OS (I'm assuming Android based on the Java references), device model, geographic location, etc.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash. Crash is coming from Google's test devices, not from real users (device: sdk_goog3_x86_64 android 13). This is in internal testing, no one else has access.

Comment: If it's through internal testing, can you pin point what steps take place before the crash happens and is logged? Or do you mean that the devices that Google is using to review your app are causing the issue?

Comment: Which version of the Crashlytics SDK are you using?

Comment: This is flutter, so I am using this package, not the SDK: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics. Not sure what SDK are they using internally, but I'd assume the latest or close to latest...

Comment: add 4 spaces before #01 on each row and the run flutter symbolize -i ./build/symbols/stack.txt -d ./build/symbols/app.android-arm64.symbols